# Accessing appSearchData bundle from ContentProvider

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

An activity is supposed to be able to provide context information to a content provider like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle appSearchData = new Bundle();
    appSearchData.putByte("category", category);
    startSearch(null, false, appSearchData, false);
    return true;
}
```

Search suggestions and results from the provider should be limited to 'category', but I can't find where to access the appSearchData bundle from my ContentProvider.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a parameter to a Custom Search Suggestion ContentProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947016/pass-a-parameter-to-a-custom-search-suggestion-contentprovider)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for onSearchRequested:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    if(searchManager!=null)
    {
        // start the search with the appropriate searchable activity
        // so we get the correct search hint in the search dialog
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("context", indicator);
            searchManager.startSearch(null, false,new ComponentName(this, YourClass.class), b, false);
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

And this is your searchable class:

```
Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA);
```

Comment: @bitbox Sorry for late response, you get it by simply calling the "getIntent()" method:

Intent intent = getIntent() in the onCreate

Comment: The question is about the content provider which returns search suggestion, not about the search activity.